# Unknown characters like â€ in the string

Tags: php, encoding

I'm getting unknown characters when I echo data on web page. `testing.doc` contains

> buy the stock "cheap" before the rest of the market

```
$data = file_get_contents('testing.doc');

$soap->SetLocalTemplate(
   array(
        'template' => base64_encode($data),
        'format'   => 'doc'
    )
);

$soap->CreateDocument();
        $result = $soap->RetrieveDocument(
            array(
                'format' => 'txt'
            )
        );

$data = $result->RetrieveDocumentResult;
file_put_contents(file.txt', base64_decode($data));
```

If i read the text file file.txt I get the exact text as stored in testing.doc but if I do like this :

```
echo base64_decode($data);
```

I get

> buy the stock â€œcheapâ€ before the rest of the market

Now there are some unknown characters. Please tell me how resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you try `header('content-type:text/html;charset=utf8');` . XML is often in UTF-8 (a good encoding to use pretty much always nowadays, at least for new projects).

Comment: add the code I supplied (assuming it is HTML) before you output any text. Then do your echo.

Comment: I'm using this code inside zencart directory. If I place this code in any other directory or in root directory it works fine and no character is printed wrongly. Do you suggest anything now?

Comment: I did so but it does not solve the problem.

Comment: Maybe there is another header being set later which overrides it. Not really familiar with zencart, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a character encoding issue.

If the encoding set your web page is using differs from the source where you're grabbing content from, then you will get funny characters like the above.

Comment: Use the same encoding on your web page as your source file.

Comment: My source file is a doc file. Can you tell me which encoding it will have?

Comment: It could be anything; only the document author will be able to tell you what character encoding they saved it in.

Comment: What do you think the encoding scheme for simple text file is?

Comment: *sigh* Like I say, it could be anything. All I could do is guess.

Answer (score 0):

Your page is probably treated as ISO-8859-1 encoded, but the XML data is in UTF-8.

Either change your output encoding to UTF-8, or use  [`iconv()`](http://www.php.net/iconv) to convert it to ISO-8859-1.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, XML data has UTF-8 encoding.

For echoing things to a browser, you should set the header, especially when you know the encoding of what you're trying to echo:

```
header('content-type:text/html;charset=utf8');
```

This goes right before the call to echo. For example:

```
/* get content, set it to $content */

header('content-type:text/html;charset=utf8');
echo $content;
```